# YII: Validate does not populate model unless there is a rule?

Tags: yii

What am I missing here. I've got a model with a bunch of variables:

```
class Car extends CFormModel
{  
  public $item1;
  public $item2;
}
```

If I post the form with item1 = "one" and item2 = "two" and I do the following in the controller:

```
if(isset($_POST['Car'])) 
{ 

    $model->attributes = $_POST['Car']; 
    if($model->validate()) {

      print_r($model);
    ...
...
```

At the point where I print the model, none of the items have values. But I add this to my model:

```
public function rules()
{
return array( array('item1', 'required'));
}
```

Then item1 populates, but not item2. How then do you get the values for OPTIONAL fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not assign any validation rules to property then this property is "unsafe". If property is unsafe then you cannot mass assign anything there, however you can directly assign the variable.

```
$model->item1 = $_POST{'car']['item1'];
```

If you are trying to mass assign variables you should also see a warning in Yii trace log.

To read property, read it directly from property

```
var_dump($model->item1);
```

Comment: So you have to apply validation even to optional fields?

Comment: You can mark them as safe - array('item1, item2', 'safe'); But it is always good idea to validate your data.